# Swallowed very little and porous plastic parts. Might it be dangerous?

Tags: toxicity, metabolism, plastic, swallow-swallowing, foreign-body-object

I ate something with my headphones on, and after eating I noticed that the ear speaker lose their covering film. I noticed as after lunch I touched them and had little black particles of the cover in my hand (guess this is due to the aging of the plastic film). Then I noticed them also on my desk, so surely some of them might haven fallen on my lunch, or even I had some on my fingers before.

Now I am concerned that I have eaten some of these plastic parts. They are very thin and not hard, so they might get resolved in my stomach acid (and do not pass through as I had written elsewhere when plastic gets swallowed).

How harmful might that be? That my body might absorb little fragments and particles of plastic??